# Only validate new subdocuments on parent save in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schemas:

```
var childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   aValue: {
      type: String
      validate: {
         validator: aValidator
      }
   }
})

var parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   children: [childSchema]
})
```

Every time a new child is added to the parent and the parent is saved, the validator will be executed for all children of that parent. This causes a lot of unnecessary calculations as previously saved subdocuments have already been validated.

Perhaps I have missed something here but is there a way to prevent validation on all subdocuments on every save?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [validateBeforeSave](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#validateBeforeSave) option in the docs for preventing the validation before save and handling it manually.

If you set this to `false` you can then manually validate the record (only the parts of it that you want to make sure are valid) and then save it.

Code from the docs for your convenience:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String });
schema.set('validateBeforeSave', false);
schema.path('name').validate(function (value) {
    return v != null;
});

var M = mongoose.model('Person', schema);
var m = new M({ name: null });

m.validate(function(err) {
    console.log(err); // Will tell you that null is not allowed.
});
m.save(); // Succeeds despite being invalid
```

But other than that the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) are pretty straight forward:

> Validation is asynchronously recursive; when you call Model#save, **sub-document validation is executed as well**. If an error occurs, your Model#save callback receives it

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the validateBeforeSafe should be set to false on the child schema to prevent validation only of the child documents?